# How to control and identify multiple Raspberry Pi's installed in multiple networks

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi, iot

I have installed multiple raspberry Pi's in multiple houses and each raspberry pi control's its appropriate house.

I have also developed an android app that control's these houses, each User can login using his phone number and control his house. How to identify each Raspberry Pi and send the user's command (e.g., Bedroom Light On) to the correct Raspberry Pi.

Everyone says to identify it using its IP address, I tried to set a static IP address to each Raspberry Pi, but once the router resets, the IP changes. How to identify each Raspberry Pi permanently.

Comment: you should have more security than a phone number, but either way, if its a user based account, why cant you adjust a setting by the user... and not the raspberry pi? if i change the tempature on my nest from accross the country, im changing it based on my login information, not by the nest itself. the nest is on my account, so i fi change the them of the nest on my account, the nest will now adjust. seems like you are overthinking this.

Comment: Yes but how to identify each Raspberry Pi to its appropriate user. The IP adress can change if the router resets. 
For example :
Let's say that HOME1 is identified by this IP address 111.111.111.111.
To send a command to HOME1, the Application will send it to the defined endpoint, which will be for exmaple IPADDRESS/command1/command2
when the IP Adress changes  the endpoint will no longer be functional.

Comment: who cares if the ip address changes. the ip address has nothing to do with the internet connectivity of a device. it goes by users. for example, if i log in to House # 1 with userid of 123, my settings will load. then, if i login to House #2 with userid of 123, my settings will be there too. IP address has nothing to do with it.... the ONLY thing that matters if that the raspberry pi makes a call to the server to get the information for a specific user (that is signed in) to that pi.

Comment: Thank you soldforapp for your comments. You seem to know the problem that I'm asking. To make it clearer, I have school final project that is creating a Home Automation System using the Raspberry Pi. That's why I'm using only phone number authentication (Firebase)The system consists of installing a Raspberry Pi in each home (There has to be no limits to the homes that can be added) and to also create an Android app that can control all of these houses.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is installed manually in each house and a user account is created with all details of that specific house (Number of peripherals, rooms...) The User then can login to the app and control his home. The problem is how to identify each house to his appropriate user, I am using firebase as database and server.

Comment: you need to link the user to the pi, yes? give each pi a UUID. when the user creates an account, link the phone number and the pi's UUID together. then, when you want to change something on the pi, the logged in user and ONLY change the UUID they are associated with. you need to think about CONNECTED devices wirelessly. UUID --> USERID (phone number) will do that. so, if I logout of the house and then log in to the same pie with another ID, it would block me out saying "only xxx can access this network" etc.

Comment: I see. So when a new house is added, in FireBase I will add
       - Phone Number of the User
       - Endpoints of that specific Raspberry Pi to which the app will send commandes.

The Endpoints is the problem, if the IP address of the Raspberry Pi changes that won't create a problem ?

Comment: You should only make *outbound* connections *from* the pi to a server in the cloud.  Then the IP address of the pi will be irrelevant, all that will matter is that it holds a unique secret such an the private part a key for which you have signed a certificate against its serial number, which you will assign on the server to be associate with a particular user's home.

Answer (score 1):

Break it down like this...

1) When a user creates an account on the network, pass in a UUID and their phone number. This will now be their account. If they log out of the account, and login to any other pi, it will pick up THEIR UUID and adjust the information accordingly.

2) When a user logs in, their phone number and the UUID is saved to Firebase. This will pair the two together.

3) The user should only be able to adjust settings on THEIR home's pi (UUID).

4) The UUID will be linked to the number. So even if I go to 500 homes with this technology, I can login the network with my phone number, and it will pick up MY pi's UUID.

5) ONLY create a UUID associated with the pi/user when its my FIRST time loading the app OR creating an account. This is make sure that a single user will not have multiple pi's (unless you want this as a feature).

As long as you link the USER to the UUID, internet will never ever matter. My IPs aren't static, yet I can change my Google Home devices(NEST) at any time because it is associated with MY account.

Comment: Thank you, I will go through it again and let you know about the results.

Comment: best of luck, have fun